# No service while customize a new User Context Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, ef-core-2.1, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I'm stuck trying to create a User and a new context to add fields to the AspNetUsers table.

I am surprised that the error indicates that there is no service for the context I created when I think I changed the code correctly.

I have currently completed the following steps:

1. Add all Razor Identity pages by creating a new context 'jakformulaireContext'.
2. In jakformularUser, I added all the fields I need.
3. I deleted the existing db (which had been generated automatically with ApplicationDbContext).
4. I did the migration of jakformulaireContext.
5. I made an Update Database and the fields were created in my new DB.
6. I also modified the startup.cs file, here is the modified piece of code:

   ```
   services.AddDbContext<jakformulaireContext>(options =>
       options.UseSqlServer(
           Configuration.GetConnectionString("jakformulaireContextConnection")));
   services.AddDefaultIdentity<jakformulaireUser>()
       .AddEntityFrameworkStores<jakformulaireContext>();
   ```

I followed a Microsoft tutorial for this but when I start the site the error is this:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[jak.formulaire.Models.jakformulaireContext]' has been registered.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)

Stack Query Cookies Headers
```

**Stack**

```
nvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[jak.formulaire.Models.jakformulaireContext]' has been registered.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorPagePropertyActivator+<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<CreateActivateInfo>b__1(ViewContext context)
Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.PropertyActivator<TContext>.Activate(object instance, TContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorPagePropertyActivator.Activate(object page, ViewContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPageActivator.Activate(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, bool invokeViewStarts)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.PartialTagHelper.RenderPartialViewAsync(TextWriter writer, object model)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.PartialTagHelper.ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner.RunAsync(TagHelperExecutionContext executionContext)
AspNetCore.Views_Shared__Layout.<ExecuteAsync>b__39_1() in _Layout.cshtml
+
                                    }
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperExecutionContext.SetOutputContentAsync()
AspNetCore.Views_Shared__Layout.ExecuteAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, bool invokeViewStarts)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderLayoutAsync(ViewContext context, ViewBufferTextWriter bodyWriter)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, string contentType, Nullable<int> statusCode)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IView view, ViewDataDictionary viewData, ITempDataDictionary tempData, string contentType, Nullable<int> statusCode)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ViewResult result)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultAsync(IActionResult result)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResultFilterAsync<TFilter, TFilterAsync>()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[jak.formulaire.Models.jakformulaireContext]'` seems to suggest that it wants to use `jakformulaireContext` as the user entity. Are you sure that you haven’t mixed up the types somewhere?

Comment: Yep you are right, just found the problem >.> I had SignInManager<jakformulaireContext> instead of SignInManager<jak.formulaire.Areas.Identity.Data.jakformulaireUser>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message suggests that it is attempting to resolve `UserManager<jakformulaireContext>`, while the user manager should actually use the user entity as its generic type argument. So the type should instead be `UserManager<jakformulaireUser>`.

For the developer-facing services like `UserManager`, `RoleManager` or `SignInManager` you will usually have to use the user type as the type argument, so make sure that you haven’t mixed up the user entity type with the database context type somewhere.

Comment: Thx for your help, your first message totally covered my question and i could manage to find the issue!